# How do i set up a code to activate a workbook with yesterday's date in the title?

Tags: excel, vba, date

relatively new to VBA, so I apologize if the question seems so simple. I'm trying to activate a workbook to run my code. However, the title of the workbook will always change depending on the day. The format of the workbooks title is always "Data_20190116.xlsx"

Where, 20190116 is yesterday's date. So in other words, tomorrow's file will be named "Data_20190117.xlsx"

Any idea how i would go about doing so? I'm a little confused as to how to make the format function work for this.

Comment: The line of code published below assigns a value to the variable FileName (better use another name in this context because VBA uses that name, too). How to assign a file name to a file is unrelated to your original question. Please ask another one. To test the solution here offered enter ? Format(Date-1, """Data_""""yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx" in the Immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileName = Format(Date-1, """Data_""""yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
```